# Debian on a brix. LAN card drivers

Tags: debian, drivers, debian-installer

Im trying to install debian(`debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-gnome-desktop+nonfree.iso`) on a brix(`gb-xm12-3227`).

- [Gigabyte GB-XM12-3227 BRIX / Ultra Compact PC kit](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4604#sp)
- [Debian AMD64 ISO](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/8.1.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/)

Using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) I successfully created a bootable USB. Booting is ok.

During installation I get asked for `rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw`. Which is the firmware for the LAN card. This firmware should be in one of the `nonfree` packages (`firmware-realtek`) in the `.iso` but it keeps asking for it.

Is there something I'm missing?

Do you know of some `.iso` that works fine with the brix(`gb-xm12-3227`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-live variant at http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/firmware-8.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso (or the [current version](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/), since 8.1 is now outdated) will work better when you're trying to install with firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen's answer is correct, there is an install image WITH firmware.

I would have posted (version-independant) this link though:
http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/ .
This folder always has the latest release image.

If you dont want to download the image again or have finished the installation regardless of the missing Ethernet drivers:

Download the package from e.g. http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-realtek_0.43_all.deb

Extract or Install it on a different computer, copy /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw to a USB drive, and manually copy it to the same place on the BRIX Filesystem. Reboot.

Then, once online, 'apt-get update', and install the "real" non-free/firmware-realtek package to benefit from future firmware updates.

You can do this during the installation, by using the ALT-F2 Expert Console.
But its a lot easier to just do after the installation.